# Why does my Markercluster vanish on a stereographic projection?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, leaflet.markercluster

I am working with Leaflet and custom stereographic projections in the polar regions.

In this projection, I am handling dozens of marker positions that need to be clustered. Therefore I am using Leaflet.markercluster plugin.

My current problem is, that depending on zoom, the drag position of individual clusters, they disappear and reappear again.

I made a jsfiddle to make the error reproducible:

https://jsfiddle.net/mzg9j327/

```
 <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>

<div id="map">
</div>
```

```
#map {
  height: 600px
}
```

```
var customCRS = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:3995',
  "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs", 
  {
    origin: [-12403632.820,12403632.820], // correct origin needs to be set
    resolutions: [22600, 11300, 5650, 2825, 1412.5, 706.25, 353.125, 176.5625, 88.28125, 44.140625], // 10 example zoom level resolutions
    tileSize: 256,
    bounds: L.bounds([-1403632.820, 17760.815,22417841.080,-13082466.960]) // max bounds also need to be set
  });

var wmsBKLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://eumetview.eumetsat.int/geoserv/wms', {
  layers: 'bkg-raster:bkg-raster',
  format: 'image/png',
  transparent: true
});


var map = new L.map('map', {
  center: L.latLng(70, -10),
  zoom: 0,
  tileSize: 256,
  continuousWorld: true,
  worldCopyJump: false,
  crs: customCRS,
  layers: [wmsBKLayer]
});


var baseMaps = {
  "background": wmsBKLayer
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);
var marker1 = L.marker([-70, 0]);
var marker2 = L.marker([0, 0]);
var marker3 = L.marker([70, 0]);

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

markers.addLayer(marker1);
markers.addLayer(marker2);
markers.addLayer(marker3);

map.addLayer(markers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the polar projection and Leaflet.markercluster option [`removeOutsideVisibleBounds`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#defaults):

> Clusters and markers too far from the viewport are removed from the map for performance.

The polar projection makes the map viewport bounds potentially have smaller latitude than at its center (typically when the pole is by the center, and edges are at lower latitude). In this situation, Leaflet.markercluster reads the viewport bounds, and (incorrectly in this case) concludes that the user displays the world at lower latitude, and hides the clusters and markers "far" from these bounds.

A possible solution is simply to disable this behaviour, hoping that you do not have so many markers that you would still experience poor performance:

```js
L.markerClusterGroup({
  removeOutsideVisibleBounds: false // Disable performance optimisation
});
```

Updated live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cefnt946/